# On an VDI that allows multiple users to connect at a time, how can I configure SQL to run with a different port for each user?

Tags: sql-server, sql

I am trying to launch an application named Aura, which uses SQL as its database engine, in a VDI that allows multiple users to connect at the same time.

When the program is first launch, it works fine, but when it is launched by a second user, I receive the following error:
[From researching I figured out it must be that the software is trying to use the same port each time, and that is obviously impossible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36xgc.png)

So I went into SQL Configuration manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocol for *My Application* > IP Addresses and changed the IPV4 port into 0 (so it chooses a dynamic port every startup).

It does appear to choose a different port every startup, but this port is still shared by all all the users who connect to the system, therefore the problem remains the same.

How can I configure SQL to provide a different port for every user that logs in?

Comment: "that is obviously impossible".  You need **a lot** more research on how networking works.  I agree with @Brian_Gale below.  As far as I am aware.. NOBODY tries to isolate a fresh port for each connection FOR ANY PROTOCOL.  How is the client even supposed to know what port to connect to?? You have some other problem and this IS NOT the solution to search for.  You should give him the points for answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server allows multiple connections on the same port, so I highly doubt that the error is due to SQL Server.  What it likely is is that Aura has something in it (such as a service) that listens on port 95110.

BUT I also don't like to make random assumptions like that as it could be any number of things.  my first step - start Aura on the server, then start a command prompt session as an administrator on the server and run:

1. netstat -ab > netstat.log
2. notepad netstat.log

netstat will show you what ports are in use on your computer and what the local and remote IP's are.  Adding in -ab will show you all of the ports in use (-a) and the application that is using the port (-b).  The "> netstat.log" just outputs the stdout (standard output as opposed to the error output) to a file called netstat.log.  You can delete this after your investigation as the data is only valid after you run the command as ports in use will change over time.

In Notepad, search for 95110 to see which application is using that port.  I suspect it is either Aura or a service used by Aura that only allows a single connection.  If it IS SQL Server (highly unlikely as I know I have applications I have written that have 100's of users connecting to the same SQL Instance at the same time on the same port without any issues), my first step would be to make sure I have all of the patches applied to SQL Server and make sure that it is at a supported version for the tool.
Both version number (2016 for example) and edition (standard for example).

If I am certain that my environment is set up correctly, next step would be to reach out to Aura support.  It could very well be that Aura doesn't support a VDI environment; if it is a desktop application and expects to be running on a desktop environment, it is HIGHLY likely that it will not support a VDI environment that allows multiple users to connect to the same physical machine at the same time.

NOTE - as I don't know what this "Aura" program does or how it works, the port may change each time the service/application is started, so replace the "95110" with the port number you get from the error message at the time the error message is displayed on screen.